# How to upload multiple files in selenium for validation?

Tags: java, selenium, apex, salesforce-lightning

In a folder 5 CSV files and i need to upload one by one for validation purpose but even single file is not uploading i tried so many methods,can anyone suggest any methods, i'm doing in salesforce.

```
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cBatchMaster']//input[1]"));
uploadElement.sendKeys("E:\\Automation\\Error Inventory.csv");
```

above the code is for single file and directly i'm giving the exact file location but i want to upload the files in one folder

Thanks

Comment: Refer to: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/38475/how-to-add-multiple-files-in-selenium-web-driver-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution in C#. A similar approach can be used in Java

Use AutoITX to upload files. You would need to add AutoItX.Dotnet in your nuget package

```
using AutoIt;


public static void UploadDocument(IWebElement uploadElement, string path)
    {

        uploadElement.Click();
        AutoItX.WinActivate("Open");
        string filepath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"..\..\"),path);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        AutoItX.Send(filepath);
        AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
```

You should be able to upload multiple files from AutoIT once you are able to upload the single file

Comment: Thanks for your reply but here where i can perform my validation after file upload